# SELECT row COUNT and another row value MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get city and model + order by common model value.

Without city mysql query is preparing successfully but with city is not working.
How can i get two columns info in one query?

```
SELECT model
FROM cars
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY COUNT(model) DESC
LIMIT 6
```

**not working:** SELECT cars,model FROM cars GROUP BY model ORDER BY COUNT(model) DESC LIMIT 6

Comment: Downvote author please explain why?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you want to do is not clear.

Comment: You can hover your mouse over the downvote button on any question to see the reasons why downvotes may be given. But the comment above is essentially correct, you have not provided enough information. We cannot see your tables or data. Any answers are likely to involve guesswork or assumptions

Answer (score 1):

If you want the model/city combinations with the most rows, then include both in the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT model, city
FROM cars
GROUP BY model, city
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 6
```